# Python Mqtt/Mysql insertion ensemble breaks up after a short time

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mqtt

atm I'm working with the python paho mqtt client and mysql to store weather data (temperature/humidity) collected via an microcontroller.

The Setup:

- Raspi with raspian & MariaDB & Mosquitto Broker
- ESP8266 which publishes the data to the broker

I wrote the following code to fetch the data from the broker and to write it to the database:

**main.py**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt     #import client1
from time import sleep
import json
from Datenbank import *
from datetime import *


i=0

def on_log(client,userdata,level,buf):
    print("log: "+buf)

def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

def on_disconnect(client,userdata,flags,rc=0):
    print("Disconnected result code "+str(rc))

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):        #callback function
    topic=msg.topic
    m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("message received",m_decode)
    m_in=json.loads(m_decode)
    dbG.writeData(m_in["Temperature"],m_in["Humidity"])
    print("Data Written")
    print(datetime.now())


db=db()
db.connectToDb("WeatherStation")

broker="192.168.0.10"
client=mqtt.Client("Sensor1_Client")
client.connect(broker)
print("Connecting to broker",broker)
client.on_connect=on_connect           
client object
#client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
client.on_log=on_log
client.on_message=on_message
client.subscribe("home/Sensor1")
client.loop_forever()
```

---

**Datenbank.py**

```
import MySQLdb as db
from datetime import *

class db:

    def __init__(self):
        self.HOST = "192.168.0.10"
        self.PORT = 3306
        self.USER = "xxx"
        self.PASSWORD = "xxx"

    def connectToDb(self,DB):
        try:
            self.connection = db.Connection(host=self.HOST, port=self.PORT,
                                       user=self.USER, passwd=self.PASSWORD, db=DB)
            self.connection.autocommit(True)
            print("Connection established")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def writeData(self,temp,hum):
        now=datetime.now()
        Full_Date=now.strftime("%y.%m.%d")
        current_year=now.strftime("%Y")
        current_month=now.strftime("%m")
        current_day=now.strftime("%d")
        current_time=now.strftime("%H:%M")

        dbhandler = self.connection.cursor()
        dbhandler.execute("""INSERT INTO TempHum(Full_Date,Day,Month,Year, Time,Temperature,Humidity) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(Full_Date,current_day,current_month,current_year,current_time,temp,hum))
```

---

I loaded the scripts on the Raspi and opened the main.py via screen by typing:

"python main.py &"

This construction works fine, but after the 15 / 16 th time, the script and with it the insertion of the data stops.

I tried it at first with a simple "client.loop_start()" and "sleep(1000)" but it worked neither.

has anyone an idea why the script doesnt work?

Greetings,

Robin

Comment: Run the code in the foreground (without the &) and edit the question to include any error messages that are output when it stops working

Comment: Hi hardlib, as it seems it works fine without the &. thanks a lot for your support. greetings